# java.io.fileNOtFound Excetion error while fetching a data from api in android Stodio

Tags: java, android

```
****i'm trying to get data from an api to display train timetable. it requires me to create signature with HMAC-SHA1 algorithm, which i think i have done it properly. but somehow when i'm trying to connect with server , i'm getting error of IO file not Found Exception.
```

java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://example.com/v3/routes?devid=("supplied by api provider")&signature=("created with MAC-SHA1"). DOnt know where i have made a mistake. can't figured out. please help me ****

```
enterString baseURl = "http://example.com";
final String privateKey = "private key";**(key is supplied by api provider)**
final int devloperid = userid;  **(devloper id is provider by api provider)**
String uri = "/v2/healthCheck";

public String genrateSignature(final String baseURl, final String privateKey, final String uri, final int devloperid) throws Exception {

    String HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHIAM = "HmacSHA1";  

    StringBuilder uriWithDevloperId = new StringBuilder().append(uri).append(uri.contains("?") ? "&" : "?").append(devloperid);


    byte[] keyBytes = privateKey.getBytes();
    byte[] uriByte = uriWithDevloperId.toString().getBytes();
    Key signingKey = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHIAM);
    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA1_ALGORITHIAM);
    mac.init(signingKey);
    byte[] signatureBytes = mac.doFinal(uriByte);
    StringBuilder singnature = new StringBuilder(signatureBytes.length * 2);
    for (byte signatureByte : signatureBytes) {

        int intval = signatureByte & 0xff;
        if (intval < 0x10) {
            singnature.append("0");
        }
        singnature.append(Integer.toHexString(intval));
    }
    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(baseURl).append(uri).append(uri.contains("?") ? "&" : "?").append("devid=" +devloperid).append("&signature="+singnature.toString().toUpperCase());

    Log.i("hello", String.valueOf(url));
    return url.toString();


}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   TrasportTimeTable trasportTimeTable = new TrasportTimeTable();
    try {
        trasportTimeTable.execute(genrateSignature(baseURl,privateKey,uri,devloperid));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

public class TrasportTimeTable extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";

        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

            int data = inputStreamReader.read();

            while (data != -1) {
                char currentCharacter = (char) data;
                result += currentCharacter;

                data = inputStreamReader.read();

            }
            Log.i("result", result);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "toast recieved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
}
```